# updating counter of for-loop inside the loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I ran this Python code.

```
for i in range(1,11):

    i=i*2

    print(i,end=" ")
```

It gave the following output:
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

How is the 'i' reaching 20 and yet staying inside the loop?
Is there a new instance of 'i' being created somehow?

Comment: `i` is set anew from the next value in the `range()` sequence. You can't update it in the loop, because you are not altering the iterator.

Comment: the last time through the loop, i starts out as 10. you then multiply i by 2 before printing it, so you print 20 when you start the loop with i=10.

Comment: range(1,11) is something called a "generator" and it contains 10 specific values (1 through 10 inclusive), which it yields one at a time. Each time through the `for` statement, `i` is set to the next up of those values (1 through 10 inclusive). As Martijn said, nothing you do inside the loop affects which `i` is up next from your `range` statement the next time through your loop.

Comment: @MaxPower: `range()` is **not** a generator. It is a *sequence*, just like a list or a tuple or a string. Ranges have a length, you can index into them, you ran reverse ranges.

Comment: thanks for the correction Martijn.

Comment: thank you very much... I understand completely...thanks a lot for the lucid explanation..this is my first day on stack overflow, and it already feels so nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` **sets** the target variable each iteration. `range()` provides the values for this, nothing else. You can set `i` inside the loop body to anything you like, but that doesn't alter what the `range()` sequence will produce for the next iteration.

This is what happens:

- An iterator is created for the `range(1, 11)` sequence. It consists of a reference to the range object and and index, starting at 0.
- The next value is taken from the iterator, `range(1, 11)[0]`, producing 1

  - `i = 1` is executed, and the loop body is started
  - In the loop body, `i = i * 2` is executed, setting `i` to 2
  - `i` is printed, the loop body ends
- The iterator index is incremented to 1.
- The next value is taken from the iterator, `range(1, 11)[1]`, producing 2

  - `i = 2` is executed, and the loop body is started
  - In the loop body, `i = i * 2` is executed, setting `i` to 4
  - `i` is printed, the loop body ends
- The iterator index is incremented to 2.
- The next value is taken from the iterator, `range(1, 11)[2]`, producing 3

  - `i = 3` is executed, and the loop body is started
  - In the loop body, `i = i * 2` is executed, setting `i` to 6
  - `i` is printed, the loop body ends

This continues on until the loop body for `range(1, 11)[9]` has been processed; there is no `range(1, 11)[10]` so the loop ends.

At no point does setting `i` to a different value in the loop alter how the loop runs. You'd have to alter the iterable, the object the `for` loop iterates over, to alter how the loop runs:

```
>>> list_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for i in list_of_numbers:
...     discard = list_of_numbers.pop()  # making the list shorter!
...     print(i)
...
1
2
```

Now the loop ends early, because we removed elements from the iteratable, and the end is reached 'early'.